# Motion blur robust edge detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, edge-detection, motion-blur

I need to detect squares on an image (for AR marker detection). Squares are rotated in 3D (meaning their projection I'm seeing isn't really a square but a 4 sided polygon). My problem is that the polygons I need to detect are moving so they are subject to motion blur. Squares are black with a white margin so there's a high contrast.
My approach for detection was to detect edges (canny for example), find contours, approximate polygons and filter them by the number of sides and maybe some other geometrical constraints.

What approach would you recommend for detecting edges on an image with a motion blur?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Harris corner detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) to detect the corner points and then use [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to [detect the lines](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6902/opencv-243-rectangle-detection/). Using the position of the corners and lines it is possible to get the polygons.